# Qual a origem do ditado "mais vale um pássaro na mão do que dois voando"?

Tags: expressões, ditados

Gostaria de saber como surgiu o ditado:

> Mais vale um pássaro na mão que dois voando.

Comment: Temos colegas aqui que poderiam localizar as primeiras menções a essa expressão, mas eu diria que a ideia expressa nesse ditado certamente precede a linguagem escrita, provavelmente a falada até.

Comment: Note-se que este ditado é comum também em Portugal. Por certo terá uma origem antiga.

Comment: Em Portugal,  "que dois a voar"

Answer (score 5):

Existem versões deste provérbio em várias línguas há muito tempo. Temos uma logo num manuscrito do século XIII em Inglaterra, mas em latim. Faz parte duma lista de provérbios que segundo [Thomas Wright (*Literature, Popular Superstitions, and History of Enlgand of the Middle Ages*, 1846p. 146-7)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=LzQEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA147&dq=%22valet%20in%20manibus%20avis%20unica%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHk_-Cqqn1AhVHxhoKHSsHDPEQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=%22valet%20in%20manibus%20avis%20unica%22&f=false) são traduções de ditado ingleses da altura:

> Plus valet in manibus avis unica quam dupla silvis
> Mais vale um pássaro na mão que dois na floresta

Depois, incluindo em português, por ordem de antiguidade:

> 1399 em italiano ([Franco Sacchetti, *Trecentonovelle*](https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Il_Trecentonovelle/CXCVIII))
> Egli è meglio pincione in mano, che tordo in frasca
> É melhor um tentilhão na mão do que um tordo na ramagem [o tordo é maior que o tentilhão]
>
> 1545 em alemão  ([Sebastian Francken, *Sprüchwörter Gemeiner Tütscher Nation*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=L1NOAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PT766&dq=%22Spatz%20in%20der%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqvpej7d3gAhUPmRoKHZiMBLw4tAEQ6AEIcTAL#v=snippet&q=%22Spatz%20in%20der%22&f=false))
> Es ist besser ein spatz in der hand dann ein storck im lufft
> É melhor um pardal na mão que uma cegonha no ar
>
> **1555 em português** ([Jorge Ferreira de Vasconcelos, *Comédia Eufrósina*](https://archive.org/details/comdiaeufrosin00vascuoft/page/n73/mode/2up?view=theater&q=passaro))
> Vos señor cuidais levar me aa toa [a reboque] de vossas esperanças […] nam ei de comer dessa galantaria nem lingoagem mas do meu trabalho […] que eu sou de **mais val um passaro na mão que dous que vam voando**
>
> 1605 em espanhol ([Cervante, *Don Quixote*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=JEQoAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA542&dq=%22m%C3%A1s%20vale%20p%C3%A1jaro%20en%20mano%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjxoeIxqrjAhUd6OAKHdOlBno4PBDoAQijATAR#v=onepage&q=%22m%C3%A1s%20vale%20p%C3%A1jaro%20en%20mano%22&f=false))
> más vale pájaro en mano que buitre volando
> [...] abutre voando (para que queriam eles o abutre é que eu não sei)

Possivelmente mais antigo que tudo isto são as variações do provérbio que aparecem em várias versões das [histórias de Ahiqar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Story_of_Ahikar), nomeadamente nas versões em eslavo eclesiástico, árabe, arménio e siríaco. Os textos mais antigos destas versões são do século XV, mas segundo Conyable, Harris e Lewis ([*The Story of Ahikar from the Aramaic, Syriac…*, 1913, p. 172](https://archive.org/details/cu31924026927776/page/n279)), a versão arménia já existia no século V (é citada em obras dessa época), e a siríaca terá sido a fonte da arménia, devendo portanto ser ainda mais antiga. Naturalmente não podemos ter a certeza se o provérbio já lá estava no princípio ou se foi acrescentado mais tarde por copistas (a história tem uma longa lista de provérbios, os ensinamento de Ahiqar ao sobrinho, e as listas das várias versões não são exatamente iguais). A história é ainda mais antiga. Foram encontrados fragmentos dela em aramaico em papiros do século V antes de Cristo. Só que… o provérbio não está nesses fragmentos. Fica aqui a minha tradução da tradução inglesa dum excerto da [versão árabe (p. 136)](https://archive.org/details/cu31924026927776/page/n239/mode/2up?q=%22a%20sparrow%20in%20thy%20hand%22&view=theater) com o provérbio e outros semelhantes:

> 45. Ó meu filho! um amigo que está perto é melhor que um excelente irmão que está longe.
>     […]
> 46. Ó meu filho! a perna de uma rã na tua mão vale mais do que um ganso na panela do teu vizinho; e um carneiro ao pé de ti é melhor do que um boi longe; e **um pardal na tua mão é melhor que mil pardais voando**;

E podem ainda ver as passagens correspondentes da versão em [eslavo eclesiástico (p. 6)](https://archive.org/details/cu31924026927776/page/n109/mode/2up?q=%22a%20sparrow%20held%20tight%22&view=theater), da versão [arménia (p. 30)](https://archive.org/details/cu31924026927776/page/n133/mode/2up?view=theater&q=%22bird%20in%20thy%20hand%22) e da [siríaca (p. 107)](https://archive.org/details/cu31924026927776/page/n209/mode/2up?q=%22one%20sparrow%20in%20thy%20hand%22&view=theater).

Ainda mais antigo temos no século I, na [*De Garrulitate* de Plutarco](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2008.01.0287%3Asection%3D7) o mesmo provérbio mas em forma abstrata; sem referência a pássaros, mas com a mesma estrutura e mensagem (minha tradução da tradução inglesa):

> É tolo quem larga o que tem à mão para ir atrás do que está fora de alcance

### Conjeturas sobre a criação do provérbio

Diz o blog [Saiba História](https://saibahistoria.blogspot.com/2010/07/blog-post.html) que o provérbio é uma tradição dos antigos caçadores, que achavam melhor capturar um pássaro que estivesse ferido no chão do que tentar atingir pássaros no ar. Só que não nos dizem como é que sabem isso, nem sequer que caçadores são esses, se portugueses no século XVI, se ingleses no século XIII, ou outro povo e tempo quaisquer. Pelo que estou em crer que aquela explicação não passa duma especulação apresentada com certeza.

Os exemplos mais antigos que vi nas línguas que consigo decifrar, os que citei e outros, simplesmente listam ou usam o provérbio e não dão qualquer indicação da sua origem. O mais certo é já terem circulado oralmente muito antes de terem sido escritos. De qualquer maneira, a mensagem metafórica do provérbio — mais vale o pouco que é garantido que o muito que tens pouca ou nenhuma chance de conseguir — é tão transparente que qualquer um o poderia ter inventado num contexto qualquer. Os provérbios que dão um ensinamento são normalmente metafóricos; o ouvinte imagina a situação descrita no provérbio, e de lá tira o ensinamento relevante para a situação presente. Por exemplo, para usar um provérbio que espero que poucos conheçam (só o ouvi ao meu pai), se alguém disser, a Rosinha é tão feiinha, não vai conseguir casar; e eu responder, há sempre um chinelo velho para o pé coxo, toda a gente vai entender, e é duvidoso que isto alguma vez tenha tido algo que ver com pés ou chinelos.

Comment: Agora já sei de onde sai esse: than two in the bush. Qua qua qua. *quam dupla silvis*. Gozado que em português saiu floresta e em inglês arbusto.

Comment: @Lambie, "floresta" é a minha tradução; o ditado em português, diz que os pássaros estão "voando"; não se sabe se na floresta ou não. Em inglês há uma versão antiga que diz que os pássaros estão "in the wood"; e noutra mais antiga ainda, estão "in the sky above", como presumivelmente no português (vê ["how many birds in the bush" no ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/509497/how-many-birds-in-the-bush). Estes pássaros são danados: vão para todo o lado... :)

Answer (score 2):

"Mais vale um pássaro na mão que dois voando: Significa que é melhor ter pouco que ambicionar muito e perder tudo. É tradição de antigos caçadores. Eles achavam melhor apanhar logo a ave que tinham atingido de raspão, antes que ela fugisse, do que tentar atirar nas que estavam voando e errar o alvo."

Você pode ver o significado e a origem desse e de muitos outros ditados e provérbios aqui nesse site:
https://saibahistoria.blogspot.com/2010/07/blog-post.html

Comment: Oi Thai, seja bem-vinda ao site! Essa explicação do 'Saiba História' parece especulativa, você teria uma fonte mais sólida que uma postagem de blog?

Comment: Obrigada, stafusa, pela acolhida. Pois é, infelizmente não encontrei nenhuma fonte bibliográfica. Por isso que coloquei a fonte... pra ficar claro que é um blog apenas. Entretanto, algumas expressões que já conheço estão descritas corretamente no blog, portanto pode ser que essa esteja também.

Comment: Acho válido, no mínimo fica registrado aqui no Portuguese SE.

Comment: Sim, obrigado Thai, creio ser válido a info do blog.