# Qual é a origem da palavra "Olá"?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, origem

Estava a ler [este artigo da National Geographic](https://www.natgeo.pt/historia/2022/03/41-palavras-portuguesas-de-origem-persa) que diz

> Olá – «wa Allah”, Deus

Realmente é parecido foneticamente mas não sei se o artigo está correto...

Comment: Não entendi essa. Falam “de origem persa”, mas falam de origem árabe, sendo que o persa é uma língua indo-européia e o árabe não. Será que *olá* já foi contração de *oxalá*? De qualquer modo, o site estaria errado...

Comment: @Schilive, semanticamente parece-me uma granda salto de *oxalá* para *olá*. O artigo parece-me altamente especulativo. E sem fontes nenhumas... Também diz que o ditado "mais vale uma pássaro na mão que dois a voar" é de origem árabe, o que me parece muito duvidos pelo [que eu vi do assunto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5846/qual-a-origem-do-ditado-mais-vale-um-p%c3%a1ssaro-na-m%c3%a3o-do-que-dois-voando)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *National Geographic* não diz, e eu não faço ideia, onde é que eles foram buscar essa ideia. Segundo o dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) não se sabe ao certo; diz apenas que é provavelmente de formação expressiva (desenvolvo algumas abreviações):

> **olá** *interjeição* (1572 cf. IAVL) usado como saudação ou como chamamento; expressa também espanto ꙩ ETIMOLOGIA provavelmente vocábulo expressivo; formas históricas 1572 *oula*, 1836 *olá*

O dicionário da [Real Academia Española](https://dle.rae.es/hola?m=form) diz também a respeito de *hola* (mesmo que *olá* em português), que é “voz expressiva”, e relaciona com o inglês *hello* e o alemão *hallo*.

Mas o [dicionário do Solano Constâncio de 1836](https://books.google.pt/books?id=HM9TAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA727&dq=%22de%20chamar%20pessoa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXo8Dembz2AhWWSvEDHetzCucQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22de%20chamar%20pessoa%22&f=false) diz que ***olá* vem de *ó* + *lá***:

> ÓLÁ! interj. (*ó* ou *oh*, e *lá*) de chamar pessoa que está em alguma distância mas que pode ouvir a nossa voz.

Note-se que segundo ele, *olá* não era saudação, apenas interjeição de chamamento. Isto corresponde basicamente ao francês *holà*, que segundo o [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/hol%C3%A0/40149) “se usa para chamar, atrair a atenção” e vem precisamente de *ho* + *là*. O [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/hol%C3%A0) indica a mesma origem, e segundo eles [*ho*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/ho) e [*là*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/l%C3%A0) correspondem basicamente aos nossos *ó* e *lá*.

Portanto se o Solano Constâncio estiver certo, *olá* terá começado como *ó lá!*, que seria um pouco como o chamamento *ó tu aí*, que se usa por vezes hoje em dia em Portugal.

Comment: Talvez "ó de lá" e não apenas "ó lá".
Ana C.